# Convert text file with colon-separated values to html table

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have a big file with more than 10000 records formatted as below.

This needs to be converted to a html table

I tried various ways of converting into csv and then to html etc, but I have so far not been able to get the desired output

`Data.txt`

```
Name       : john
age        : 20
tag id     : 1234567
Name       : Mark
age        : 40
tag id     : 832245
Name       : tom
age        : 60
tag id     : 789324
......
```

I want this to be converted into a "html" table like this:

```
Name    Age   Tagid
John     20   1234567
Mark    40     832245
tom     60     789324
```

I need to process files of 10000 records. How can I do that?

Comment: brain storming: use sed get rid of "name", "age" "id" ":" in first pass. sed 2nd pass: create csv. print <html5 stuff> name Age ID</> read that csv to the webpage. then you woulnt need awk. use csv to create a real data base later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be much shorter, if I knew how to do multiple search replaces in sed. i dont. Oh well. after that, it got silly.  no awk required. im assuming your data file is named bs.dat and that you want a csv for migrating to a real data base system later.  output to an awesome html file too... may need some css. This lousy output is html5 compliant. (as is)

```
#!/bin/bash
touch me lel.html
rm me lel.html
touch me p1 p2 p3 p4 lel.html
#Fix BS data make a proper csv
c=","
#remove spaces
cat bs.dat  | sed 's/ //g' > p1
#remove Name:
cat p1  | sed 's/Name://g' > p2
#Remove age:
cat p2  | sed 's/age://g' > p3
#remove tagid:
cat p3  | sed 's/tagid://g' > p4
#make a csv
file=p4
i=1
while read line
    do
        if [ "$i" = "1" ]; then
            l1=$line$c && i=2 
        elif [ "$i" = "2" ]; then
            l2=$l1$line$c && i=3
        elif [ "$i" = "3" ]; then
            l3=$l2$line >> me && i=1 && echo $l3 >> me
        else
            echo "something went wrong: $line"
        exit
        fi    
    done <"$file"
rm p1 p2 p3 p4
#Cool now we have a proper csv for later when we need to migrate to a real database
#ok lets make some html
touch lel.html

echo "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\">" > lel.html
echo "<meta content=\"code, bash, lolz\" name=\"keywords\" /><title>IDK what</title></head><body>" >> lel.html
echo "<pre>Name          Age          ID  " >> lel.html
while IFS=, read col1 col2 col3
do
    echo "$col1 $col2 $col3" >> lel.html
done < me

echo "</pre></body></html>" >> lel.html 
firefox lel.html
```

Given that you have a large data file, you may opt to remove the p1-p4 files earlier. 
the csv output will be a smaller file, as will  all the consecutive outputs, but it is disk intensive, I made Zero effort for efficiency & resource usage conservation.

Also:The Names will be Pushed together. Wait, I don't see FirstName LastName in this data. I assume they actually exist but were omitted for simplicity...There is a simple fix to that, using REGEX. where there is [a-z][A-Z] in the first column value, insert a space

Comment: later, i figured out how to do the or statement with sed which looks like \|

Answer (score 3):

Works with gawk or nawk, but not mawk.

```
awk -F '[[:blank:]]*:[[:blank:]]*' '
    BEGIN {print "<table><thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Age</th><th>Tagid</th></tr></thead><tbody>"}
    {
        name  = $2; getline
        age   = $2; getline
        tagid = $2
        print "<tr><td>" name "</td><td>" age "</td><td>" tagid "</td></tr>"
    }
    END {print "</tbody></table>"}
' Data.txt > Data.html
```

This assumes that there will be exactly 3 lines for each record, in the order name, age, tagid

Comment: ... and please check your field delimiter(`'[[:blank:]]*:[[:blank:]]*'`). It does not recognize the fields by that delimiter.

Comment: @KasiyA I think that may be a matter of which awk your system is using: it appears to work in `gawk` (but IIRC Ubuntu uses `mawk` by default).